# Baixar arquivos na WebView no android 6.0

Tags: android

Estou utilizando o seguinte código para baixar arquivos na web view:

```
        @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")public void onDownloadStart(String url,String userAgent,String contentDisposition,String mimetype,long contentLength){
            DownloadManager.Request request =new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));                
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();final String filename =URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype);          
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, filename);               
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/Download", filename);DownloadManager dm =(DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);          
            dm.enqueue(request);Intent intent =new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);             
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);    
            intent.setType("*/*");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Baixando",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}}); //
```

O mesmo está funcionando normalmente no Android 4.0 ICS, mas no Android 6.0 não acontece nada. Nesse caso, que seria necessário para realizar downloads no Android  6.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que seu problema está que a partir da API 23 as permissões devem ser verificadas antes da ação acontecer, não basta colocar no manifest.xml.

Esta função pode ajudar você:

```
public  boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
    if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
        return true;
    } else {

        Log.v(TAG,"Permission is revoked");
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
        return false;
    }
}
else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
    Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
    return true;
}
```

}

Espero possa ajudar.
Abraços.

Comment: Obrigado Marcelo, depois de sua resposta eu realmente acredito que seja isso. Estou tentando acrescentar o seu código ao meu mas estou tendo alguns problemas e tive que modifico-lo bastante, receio que não vai funcionar logo de primeira, mas já estou aceitando sua resposta como correta. Valeu.

Comment: Claro...vai ter que adaptar principalmente se você estiver usando fragment mas esse é o core.....espero possa funcionar, pelo menos é um início para que você possa procurar por mais informação. Boa sorte.